# Java + Jena + Rdf : need help writing the correct sparql Query

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

I have a RDF file like this one (`test.rdf`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:vocab="http://www.datiopen.it/rdf/resource/vocab/" xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" xmlns:db="http://www.datiopen.it/rdf/resource/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:map="http://www.datiopen.it/rdf/resource/#" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xml:base="http://www.datiopen.it/rdf/resource/" >
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label">
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici">
<rdfs:label>Trentino-Alto Adige - Beni architettonici ed artistici</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_do_serialuid">
<rdfs:label>Serial Id</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_gid">
<rdfs:label>gid</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_comune">
<rdfs:label>Comune</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_provincia">
<rdfs:label>Provincia</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_regione">
<rdfs:label>Regione</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_loc_no">
<rdfs:label>Localit&#224;</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_no">
<rdfs:label>Nome</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_via_no">
<rdfs:label>Indirizzo</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_immuso_no">
<rdfs:label>Uso</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_immtpl_no">
<rdfs:label>Tipo</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_data_agg">
<rdfs:label>Data aggiornamento</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_tp_tutela">
<rdfs:label>Tipo tutela</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_cd">
<rdfs:label>Codice immobile</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_prov_cd">
<rdfs:label>Codice provincia</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_cmp_cd">
<rdfs:label>Codice CMP</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_com_cd">
<rdfs:label>Codice comune</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_fraz_cd">
<rdfs:label>Codice Frazione</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_immtpl_cd">
<rdfs:label>Codice tipo immobile</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_immuso_cd">
<rdfs:label>Codice uso immobile</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_prt_cd">
<rdfs:label>codice immobile PRT</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_prt">
<rdfs:label>PRT</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_cd_tutela">
<rdfs:label>Codice tutela</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_categoria">
<rdfs:label>Categoria</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_selez">
<rdfs:label>Selezione</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_label_2ad">
<rdfs:label>Etichetta_2AD</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_label">
<rdfs:label>Etichetta</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_glatitude">
<rdfs:label>DO_Y</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici_glongitude">
<rdfs:label>DO_X</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="view_tbeni_architettonici/1">
<rdfs:label>view_tbeni_architettonici #1</rdfs:label>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_do_serialuid rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">1</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_do_serialuid>
<dcterms:coverage rdf:resource="http://spcdata.digitpa.gov.it/Comune/H517" />
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_loc_no></vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_loc_no>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_no>Chiesa di S. Antonio abate</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_no>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_via_no></vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_via_no>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immuso_no>CHIESA</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immuso_no>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immtpl_no>CHIESA</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immtpl_no>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_data_agg>10/04/2001</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_data_agg>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_tp_tutela>DICHIARATO DI INTERESSE CULTURALE AI SENSI DEL D.LGS. 22/01/2004 N. 42</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_tp_tutela>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_cd>155.0004</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_prov_cd>22</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_prov_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_cmp_cd>6</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_cmp_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_com_cd>155</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_com_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_fraz_cd>0</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_fraz_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immtpl_cd>18</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immtpl_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immuso_cd>7</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immuso_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_prt_cd>2</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_prt_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_prt>ECCLESIASTICA</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_prt>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_cd_tutela>1.00000000000</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_cd_tutela>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_categoria>Beni religiosi</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_categoria>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_selez>1</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_selez>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_label_2ad>T244</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_label_2ad>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_label>T245</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_label>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_glatitude>46.3958455087868</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_glatitude>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_glongitude>11.1224323995498</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_glongitude>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="view_tbeni_architettonici/2">
<rdfs:label>view_tbeni_architettonici #2</rdfs:label>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_do_serialuid rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">2</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_do_serialuid>
<dcterms:coverage rdf:resource="http://spcdata.digitpa.gov.it/Comune/H517" />
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_loc_no></vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_loc_no>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_no>Maso S. Bartolomeo</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_no>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_via_no></vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_via_no>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immuso_no>ABITAZIONE</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immuso_no>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immtpl_no>MASO</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immtpl_no>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_data_agg>10/04/2001</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_data_agg>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_tp_tutela>DICHIARATO DI INTERESSE CULTURALE AI SENSI DEL D.LGS. 22/01/2004 N. 42</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_tp_tutela>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_cd>155.0001</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_prov_cd>22</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_prov_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_cmp_cd>6</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_cmp_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_com_cd>155</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_com_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_fraz_cd>0</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_fraz_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immtpl_cd>26</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immtpl_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immuso_cd>1</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immuso_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_prt_cd>3</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_prt_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_prt>PRIVATA</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_prt>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_cd_tutela>1.00000000000</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_cd_tutela>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_categoria>Manufatti insediativi</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_categoria>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_selez>0</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_selez>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_label_2ad></vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_label_2ad>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_label></vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_label>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_glatitude>46.39434215468</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_glatitude>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_glongitude>11.1090853812521</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_glongitude>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici"/>
</rdf:Description>
.....
.....
.....
<rdf:Description rdf:about="view_tbeni_architettonici/1835">
<rdfs:label>view_tbeni_architettonici #1835</rdfs:label>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_do_serialuid rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">1835</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_do_serialuid>
<dcterms:coverage rdf:resource="http://spcdata.digitpa.gov.it/Comune/H506" />
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_loc_no></vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_loc_no>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_no>Eremo e Chiesa di S. Biagio</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_no>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_via_no></vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_via_no>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immuso_no></vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immuso_no>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immtpl_no>EREMO</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immtpl_no>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_data_agg>10/04/2001</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_data_agg>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_tp_tutela>DICHIARATO DI INTERESSE CULTURALE AI SENSI DEL D.LGS. 22/01/2004 N. 42</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_tp_tutela>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_cd>154.0001</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_prov_cd>22</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_prov_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_cmp_cd>6</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_cmp_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_com_cd>154</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_com_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_fraz_cd>0</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_fraz_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immtpl_cd>68</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immtpl_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immuso_cd>0</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_immuso_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_prt_cd>3</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_imm_prt_cd>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_prt>PRIVATA</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_prt>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_cd_tutela>1.00000000000</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_cd_tutela>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_categoria>Beni religiosi</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_categoria>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_selez>1</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_selez>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_label_2ad>T243</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_label_2ad>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_label>T244</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_label>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_glatitude>46.3921621030441</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_glatitude>
<vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_glongitude>11.0775100584678</vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_glongitude>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="vocab/view_tbeni_architettonici"/>
</rdf:Description>

</rdf:RDF>
```

how can I extract the rows that have the lat/lon coordinates
between a given range? I use Java and Jena to build the query following this schema code:

```java
Model m = FileManager.get().loadModel( Config.OntoBasePath +  "test.rdf" );

String queryString =    
"PREFIX db: <http://www.datiopen.it/CatalogSparql/resource/>            " +
"PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>                   " +
"PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>                           " +
"PREFIX map: <http://www.datiopen.it/CatalogSparql/resource/#>          " +
"PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>                        " +
"PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>              " +
"PREFIX vocab: <http://www.datiopen.it/CatalogSparql/resource/vocab/>   " +
"select ?subject  ?lat  ?lon                                            " +
"where {                                                                " +
"?subject rdfs:label  ?label   .                                        " +
"?subject vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_glatitude ?lat .              " +
"?subject vocab:view_tbeni_architettonici_glongitude ?lon .             " +
"FILTER( xsd:float(?lat)  - 46.39584550 <= 0.05 && 46.39584550   - xsd:float(?lat)  <= 0.05     " + 
"     && xsd:float(?long) - 11.12243239 <= 0.05 && 11.12243239 - xsd:float(?long) <= 0.05  )    " +
"}   " ;

Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
// Execute the query and obtain results
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, m);
try {
    ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
    while (results.hasNext()) {
        QuerySolution qs = results.nextSolution();
        Literal name = qs.getLiteral("x");
        System.out.println(name);
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    qe.close();
}
```

but I'm not be able to obtain the expected results. I always get an empty result set. Can someone help me to write the correct query?

Comment: Try removing parts of the query until some results are generated.  Add back the bits you removed.  You then know which part is causing the lack of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vocab` prefix looks like it should be the same in your data and your query, but it's not.  In the data, you have:

```
xmlns:vocab="http://www.datiopen.it/rdf/resource/vocab/"
```

but in your query you have

```
PREFIX vocab: <http://www.datiopen.it/CatalogSparql/resource/vocab/>
```

There are actually a few prefixes like this.  Your data (converted into Turtle for the

```
@prefix db:      <http://www.datiopen.it/rdf/resource/> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix map:     <http://www.datiopen.it/rdf/resource/#> .
@prefix vocab:   <http://www.datiopen.it/rdf/resource/vocab/> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix dcterms:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
```

and your query has these:

```
PREFIX db: <http://www.datiopen.it/CatalogSparql/resource/>             
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>                    
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>                            
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>                         
PREFIX map: <http://www.datiopen.it/CatalogSparql/resource/#>           
PREFIX vocab: <http://www.datiopen.it/CatalogSparql/resource/vocab/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
```

The prefixes `db`, `map`, and `vocab` do not match, so you're actually querying for something quite different than what's in your data.

Comment: Great! It was enough to correct the tag vocab to make sure that things would start to work! The tag db: and: map I've eliminated because not used them.
I did not realize the error. Thank you very much.